# How to truncate a .wav and underscores in a song name

Tags: ios, swift

I have a working song player but I can't figure out how to get the .wav off the end and the underscores out of the song name. When my music player was not working it was because there wasn't underscores. How would I this without changing the song file name.

```
Secure_The_Bag.wav to Secure The Bag
```

I thought this code would do it but it doesn't.

```
 var name = String()

func getName() -> String {
      return name
  }
```

AlbumSongViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SongsTableViewCell
    cell.mainLabel.text = song[indexPath.row].getName()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let songName = song[indexPath.row].getName()
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(songName)"
    print(fileURLString)
    Player.shared.playStream(fileUrl: fileURLString)

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to drop the .wav and replace the underscores with spaces?

Comment: @Magnas Yes sir

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of achieving your desired result. One of the easiest/straight forward is to use the `replacingOccurences` method.

```
var name = "Secure_The_Bag.wav"

name = name.replacingOccurrences(of: ".wav", with: "")
// name is now "Secure_The_Bag"

name = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
// name is now "Secure The Bag"
```